# Get value of json array based on variable

Tags: json

I have a json that begins like this.  I can access the User, Claim, and related first-level data with no problem.  I'm trying to access data within ClaimResponse for a specific variable (i.e. where User.id=3).  I've tried variations of

```
x.ClaimResponse[Userid].id
```

, with no luck.  Any immediate ideas at how I can get at this data?

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "User": {
            "score": "272",
            "id": "3"},
        "Claim": {
            "id": "2",
            "user_id": "3",
            "expiration": "2013-12-31 23:59:59",
            "editor_content": null,
            "point": "56.67",
            "claim_count": "3",
            "editor_pick": "0",
            "isCounterClaimed": "1",
            "headline": null,
            "subhead": null,
            "initial_point": "40",
            "claim_maker_cost": "60",
            "exp": "Dec 31, 2013"
        },
        "ClaimResponse": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "claim_id": "2",
                "expiration": null,
                "response_type": "nay",
                "source": null,
                "created": "2013-05-15 03:28:18",
                "modified": "2013-05-15 03:28:18"
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "claim_id": "2",
                "expiration": null,
                "response_type": "yeh",
                "source": null,
                "created": "2013-05-15 14:47:30",
                "modified": "2013-05-15 14:47:30"
            },
            {
                "id": "13",
                "claim_id": "2",
                "expiration": null,
                "response_type": "nay",
                "source": null,
                "created": "2013-05-15 15:59:59",
                "modified": "2013-05-15 15:59:59"
            },
            {
                "id": "50",
                "claim_id": "2",
                "expiration": null,
                "response_type": "yeh",
                "source": null,
                "created": "2013-05-24 14:32:23",
                "modified": "2013-05-24 14:32:23"
            },
            {
                "id": "71",
                "claim_id": "2",
                "expiration": null,
                "response_type": "yeh",
                "source": null,
                "created": "2013-05-29 04:37:19",
                "modified": "2013-05-29 04:37:19"
            }
(...)
```

Comment: I guess you need to use `JSON.parse()` !

Answer (score 0):

[] operator is for getting data based on index from array, e.g if ClaimResponse[0] you get user with id 4

Answer (score 0):

you can run a for loop for array got after fetching data with key ClaimResponse that returns an array.

Like

```
public static JSONObject ObjectWithIdandReponse(int _id,JSONArray responseArray) {
    for (JSONObject Obj in responseArray)
    {
     if(Obj.id==_id)
     return Obj;
    }
}
```

Make method that returns JSON Obj and pass parameter as user id and array of claims

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to grab a specific ClaimResponse with a particular id?  If so, try this:

```
var arr = x.ClaimResponse,
    userId = "3", //Set this to the uid you want
    length = arr.length,
    claim = null; //This variable stores the correct claim

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  claim = arr[i];
  if (claim.id === userId) {
    break;
  }
}
```